# Negation of formal statement of continuity

Tags: continuity, predicate-logic

I am asked to find the negation of $∀a ∈ R ∀ε > 0 ∃δ > 0 ∀x ∈ R, |x − a| < δ : |3x − 3a| < ε$

What I got is $∃a ∈ R ∃ε > 0 ∀δ > 0 ∃x ∈ R, |x − a| < δ : |3x − 3a| >= ε$, is this correct? Most of my doubt is about $∃x ∈ R$. Thanks!

Comment: But you have to use logical connectives between formulas...

Comment: The original clause is : $|x−a| < \delta \to |3x−3a| < \epsilon$. Negating it we get : $|x−a| < \delta \land |3x−3a| \ge \epsilon$.

Comment: And the $∃x ∈ \mathbb R$ is correct.